# How To Set The Array Index Value

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I want to set the array index value starting from 1, because I am showing the array index value I don't want to how the index value as Zero. I Don't know how to set the array index value from Zero.

```
Array (

[0] => "please"

[1] => "save"
[2] => "water"

)
```

I want like this:

```
Array (

[1] => "please"

[2] => "save"
[3] => "water"

)
```

I am displaying the index value in label for every object in  a collection view.
Please suggest some ideas and sample code to do this.

Comment: Always index starts from 0.We can change the object to index using insertObject or replace the object.But it must start with 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For visual representation just add 1 to your index before displaying it.

```
int indexInArray = /* whatever */;
NSString *displayedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", indexInArray + 1];
yourLabel.text = displayedString;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution

```
NSMutableArray *array1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"please", @"save",@"water", nil];
[array1 replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@" "];
[array1 replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:@"please"];
[array1 replaceObjectAtIndex:2 withObject:@"save"];
[array1 insertObject:@"water" atIndex:3];
NSLog(@"The result is - %@",array1);
```

The printed result is

```
The result is - (
" ",
please,
save,
water
)
```

Comment: thanks , but my array is not constant ,in the array i am storing images taken by camera ,in this how can i replace object one by one .Please help me .